# Why can't I get a negative number using bit manipulation in Swift?

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation

This is a LeetCode question. I wrote 4 answers in different versions of that question. When I tried to use "Bit manipulation", I got the error. Since no one in LeetCode can answer my question, and I can't find any Swift doc about this. I thought I would try to ask here.

The question is to get the majority element (>n/2) in a given array. The following code works in other languages like **Java**, so I think it might be a **general question** in Swift.

```
func majorityElement(nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    var bit = Array(count: 32, repeatedValue: 0)
    for num in nums {
        for i in 0..<32 {
            if (num>>(31-i) & 1) == 1 {
                bit[i] += 1
            }
        }
    }
    var ret = 0
    for i in 0..<32 {
        bit[i] = bit[i]>nums.count/2 ? 1 : 0
        ret += bit[i] * (1<<(31-i))
    }
    return ret
}
```

When the input is **[-2147483648]**, the output is 2147483648. But in Java, it can successfully output the right negative number.

Swift doc says :

> Even on 32-bit platforms, Int can store any value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, and is large enough for many integer ranges.

Well, it is **2,147,483,647**, the input is 1 larger than that number. When I ran `pow(2.0, 31.0)` in playground, it shows **2147483648**. I got confused. What's wrong with my code or what did I miss about **Swift Int**?

Comment: because 2,147,483,648 is actually a 33 bit number. it's `1000...00000[32 zeroes]`, whereas 2,147,483,648 is `011....111[31 ones] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java `int` is a 32-bit integer. The Swift `Int` is 32-bit or 64-bit
depending on the platform. In particular, it is 64-bit on all OS X
platforms where Swift is available.

Your code handles only the lower 32 bits of the given integers, so that

```
-2147483648 = 0xffffffff80000000
```

becomes

```
2147483648 = 0x0000000080000000
```

So solve the problem, you can either change the function to take 32-bit integers as arguments:

```
func majorityElement(nums: [Int32]) -> Int32 { ... }
```

or make it work with arbitrary sized integers by computing the
actual size and use that instead of the constant `32`:

```
func majorityElement(nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    let numBits = sizeof(Int) * 8
    var bit = Array(count: numBits, repeatedValue: 0)
    for num in nums {
        for i in 0..<numBits {
            if (num>>(numBits-1-i) & 1) == 1 {
                bit[i] += 1
            }
        }
    }
    var ret = 0
    for i in 0..<numBits {
        bit[i] = bit[i]>nums.count/2 ? 1 : 0
        ret += bit[i] * (1<<(numBits-1-i))
    }
    return ret
}
```

A more Swifty way would be to use `map()` and `reduce()`

```
func majorityElement(nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    let numBits = sizeof(Int) * 8
    let bitCounts = (0 ..< numBits).map { i in
        nums.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 >> i) & 1 }
    }
    let major = (0 ..< numBits).reduce(0) {
        $0 | (bitCounts[$1] > nums.count/2 ? 1 << $1 : 0)
    }
    return major
}
```

Comment: I tried Int32, but from your answer now I know I tried in a wrong way. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Yes, your answer do answers my question. Thank you very much! And I like  the Swifty way `map()` and `reduce()` very much! :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I forgot to choose your answer as accepted answer. Sry about that. )